# Why qmake -project know hello.cpp has main function?

Tags: c++, qt

I am new to Qt, write a base sample in hello.cpp:

```
 #include <QApplication>
#include <QLabel>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
     QApplication app(argc, argv);

     QLabel *label = new QLabel("Hello!World! Orz...");
     label->setWindowTitle("First Qt!");
     label->resize(200, 50);
     label->show();

     return app.exec();
}
```

Then I do `qmake -project` and `qmake` and `make`

And then `./GUI` .It just run!

I am confuse . why qmake know make `hello.cpp`  I never told it!

Thanks for any answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you *did* tell it, just not as explicitly as you think :-)

When you execute `qmake -project` (ie, projectfile mode), it examines your files to figure out which is the main one, and constructs a project file based on that. By default it looks at the files in your current directory but you can also control this with the `-r` (recursive search) and `-nopwd` (use only specified files, not those in the current directory) flags.

Then, then you run `qmake` with no arguments, it will use the information in that project file to construct a makefile. Then, of course, `make` will use the makefile.

This is specified in the documentation:

> qmake supports two different modes of operation. The first mode, which is the default is makefile generation. In this mode, qmake will take a .pro file and turn it into a makefile. Creating makefiles is covered by this reference guide, there is another mode which generates .pro files.
>
> To toggle between these modes you must specify in the first argument what mode you want to use. If no mode is specified, qmake will assume you want makefile mode. The available modes are:
>
> **-makefile** qmake output will be a makefile (Makefile mode).
> **-project** qmake output will be a project file (Project file mode).